# tt not shown when formatting DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

With this specific code I don't have the AM PM shown.  I tried searching Stack Overflow but did not find anything regarding this specific format.  Is there something wrong in the code that prevents the tt to be shown ?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd d MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(SessionIsFrench.Value ? "fr-CA" : "en-US"));
```

The SessionIsFrench is true

Comment: Answer would depend on what language this is, don't you think?

Comment: C# and I don't mind having a work around if the format is not right because I absolutely need this format

Comment: I don't understand why -1 as I really did search a lot believe me

Comment: Just wondering *why* you need AM/PM. AFAICS the French speaking part of Canada uses 24 hour time format, so why not just stick to that?

Comment: @Berend It's a customer request but I agree with you

Comment: Heh, that explains a lot . BTDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need the AM/PM part, you could format the date and time parts separately, and always use "en-US" for the time.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var date = now.ToString("dddd d MMMM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(SessionIsFrench.Value ? "fr-CA" : "en-US"));
var time = now.ToString("hh:mm tt", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
var dateTime = string.Format("{0} {1}", date, time);
```

Comment: Looks like even with .NET 4.5 the AM/PM is not defined for French culture as Berend said

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code, it's just that AM and PM is not defined for fr-CA.

```cs
var c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
Console.WriteLine(c.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator); // ""
Console.WriteLine(c.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator); // ""
```

Comment: You are right.  It seems not defined for that culture.